# How to check if website is up?

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning about vb.net and was wondering how I would check for a website, if it is up, set a public shared, if it is down, use a different public shared?

I currently have the code as

```
Public Shared domain As String = "domain"
```

But I'm confused as how to make it check the site when I launch the application and then run the check.

--- Edit this is what I have now,

```
Dim URL As String = "https://www.personalblog.com"

Public Shared Function IsWebpageOnline(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        Dim res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

 If IsWebpageOnline = 1 Then
Public Shared domain As String = "blog.com"
 Else
Public Shared domain As String = "backupblog.com"
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check a webpage is online or not.

```
 Public Shared Function IsWebpageOnline(ByVal URL As String) As Boolean
       Try
            Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
            Dim res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
       Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Return False
       End Try
    Return True
 End Function
```

It will try to make a get request to web server and then return a bool value

But I must suggest, switch to C# while its early.

Comment: Maybe have some actual error handling in the catch.

Comment: Yes OP can also check if the computer fails to connect, etc.

Comment: Thank you! That works to check, how do you intergrate it with a if statement for a public shared? I normally just define those variables at the start of my script but adding a if statement breaks it.

Comment: You are not sending the url parameter to `IsWebpageOnline` function.     You should check it like: `If IsWebpageOnline(URL) Then` You don't need to compare because the return type of the function is boolean already.